# How Do I Check the boundary of a Bezier Curve?

Tags: javascript, visualization, bezier, curve, boundary

I drew a river with a bezier curve by first creating a river object type, and then draw it:

```
var River= function(){
    this.end = [152,401];
    this.endControl = [263,304];
    this.frontControl = [300,453];
    this.front = [400,354];
    this.frontNode = [333,390];
    this.endNode = [229,365];
};
River.prototype.draw=function(){
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(15);
    stroke(0, 94, 255);
    bezier(this.end[0], this.end[1], this.endControl[0], this.endControl[1], this.frontControl[0], this.frontControl[1], this.front[0], this.front[1]);
};
var river= new River();
river.draw()
```

I added a sheep object type and drew some sheep on my canvas, and I want to move them around in the canvas. However, I want the sheep to stop moving when they reach the boundaries of the river.
I am thinking of writing a function such as "sheep.checkRiverBoundary()", but I don't know how. How do I check the boundaries of a bezier curve? Preferably, I want to check the curve only, not just the entire rectangle surrounding it.
I use the environment provided by the Khan Academy JS courses to code this. Great thanks to whoever answers this question.

Comment: You code is some kind of custom code, because the canvas API does not have those functions. So: if you're in HTML land, you can just exploit the fact that you could place an SVG element and use `getBoundingClientRect()` like you can for every element on the page. If that's not an option, have a look at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#boundingbox to do the work manually (but using an SVG element with a `<path d="...">` is _by far_ easier). If you're _not_ in plain HTML land, which it kind look like you aren't, there might be other options, so remember to say which framework etc you're using

Comment: (also on a JS note: JS has had class syntax for a long time now, you'll almost certainly want to use that instead of the old function + prototype assignment approach)